# ifacebook native login problems

Tags: ionic3, native, facebook-login

i have problem with Facebook native login i followed this tutorial 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/facebook
i added a button in my html file

```
    <button ion-button (tap)="loginFacebook()" icon-left block>
    <ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon>
    <div>facebook</div>
    </button>
```

and then added this function in my ts file

```
loginFacebook(){
  this.fb.login(['public_profile', 'user_friends', 'email'])
  .then((res: FacebookLoginResponse) => console.log('Logged into Facebook!', res))
  .catch(e => console.log('Error logging into Facebook', e));
}
```

but when i try to click the button nothing happens with no problem 
I'm new to coding 
thank you for help

Comment: make sure you're not testing it in ionic serve. this plugin works only on android, ios, and browser platforms. If this is not the case, then look at your console for an error after clicking the button.

Comment: @SherifAbdulmawla i'm testing it on my android phone

Comment: Then connect your device to the laptop and inspect app and check console for error